# logrotate: Remove logs left from some buggy behaviour

Tags: logrotate

In this case I talk about situation like this. We have a config for logrotate:

```
/logs/test.log {
    rotate 2
    size 1K
    missingok
    nocompress
    copytruncate
    extension .log
    maxage 60
}
```

But there can be files like these:

```
test.4.log
test.58.log
```

They left there because of some bug had been occurred.

Is there any standard way to remove them with test.3.log as well?